# what to do if two libraries has exactly the same classes?

Tags: c#

I have such error

> Error 8   The type 'System.Threading.Volatile' exists in both
>   'c:\Oleg\projects\MBClient\packages\Disruptor.1.1.0\lib\net40\Atomic.dll'
>   and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll'   C:\Oleg\projects\MBClient\MBClient\CustomIndeces\CompositeIndex.cs  77  40  MBClient

I do not know what to do as fully-qualified name doesn't identify exactly which class to use. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign an alias to the library in VS by right-clicking the assembly in your list of references, going to properties, and setting the "alias" property to whatever you want it to be. Then to use types from this assembly, you use `extern alias` at the the beginning of your namespace.

Example:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    extern alias Threading1;
    using Threading1.System.Threading.Volatile;
}
```

[`extern alias` msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

maybe you can define an [`alias`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28VS.80%29.aspx) for that namespace, example for `Timer` class is found on the following namespaces

```
using WinTimer = System.Windows.Forms;
using ThreadTimer = System.Threading;
```

then you can use it like,

```
WinTimer.Timer _tmr = new WinTimer.Timer();
ThreadTimer.Timer _Thrtmr = new ThreadTimer.Timer();
```

Comment: i don't understand what should I do in my case. both libraries has `System.Threading.Volatile` class.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of name clashes between two or more assemblies. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alias when using the library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The information in that link assumes that the classes are in two different namespaces, which is not the case here.

Comment: Sorry I thought the link covered the extern alias declaration.